# Mysql query over 2 tables and a multiple insert

Tags: mysql, subquery

I got following question.
I have two tables

```
xt_products_description 
--> products_id
--> products_name

xt_products_to_categories
--> products_id
--> categories_id
```

In the xt_products_to_categories there are multiple entries with the same "products_id" and different "categories_id". So I got many sub-categories there.

Example:

```
products_id | categories_id
1000        | 333
1000        | 334
2000        | 494
2000        | 349
```

No I got this problem.
I have multiple products which have the word "Schürze" in "xt_products_description.products_name"

```
select * from 'xt_products_description', 'xt_products_to_categories' where 'products_name" like "%Schürze%";
```

I want to give every entry that got this word one new subcategorie 'xt_product_to_categories.categories_id'

So xt_products_to_categories.product_id has to remain the same, but i want to INSERT for every item that has the word in it, a new row with my new subcategorie.

Hope I could make it a bit clear, what I'm trying to doing.
How can I archive that?
I habe many products with different products_id's and I'm searching for products with the word "Schürze" in it, and want to Insert in every product a new subcategorie.

Greets Heisenberg

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO xt_product_to_categories
    SELECT products_id, ID_OF_CATEGORY 
    FROM xt_products_description 
    WHERE products_name LIKE "%Schürze%";
```

Remember and replace `ID_OF_CATEGORY` with the appropriate id.

Comment: Thank you. If I do that: 
INSERT INTO 'xt_product_to_categories'
    SELECT 'products_id', '115' 
    FROM 'xt_products_description' 
    WHERE 'products_name' LIKE "%Schürze%";

I get following error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''xt_product_to_categories' SELECT 'products_id', '115' FROM 'xt_produ' at line 1

Comment: @Heisenberg Whoops. Typo in the SELECT. Is that any better?

Comment: Thank you. Don't see it, either.
But now I got folliwing error: "#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Comment: @Heisenberg Does your table only have two columns as in your question? If it doesn't you'll have to specify the columns you are inserting into.